# How do I catch the socket error in the TCP server of cl-async package?

Tags: common-lisp

How do I catch the unexpected disconnection of the TCP socket with `cl-async` `tcp-server`?  For example the server below cannot handle the situation when the client closes the telnet terminal forcefully. I guess I should add the handler after the `:event-cb` keyword but I don't know how I can combine with the `as:signal-handler`.

```
(require 'cl-async)
(require 'babel)

(defun my-tcp-server ()
  (format t "Starting server.~%")
    (as:tcp-server
     nil 8888  ; nil means 0.0.0.0 to listen for any address
     ;; read-cb
     (lambda (socket data)
       (let ((data-str ; stores the received data in utf8 string
          (handler-case (babel:octets-to-string data :encoding :utf-8)
        (babel-encodings:invalidutf8-continuation-byte (err)
          (declare (ignore err))
          (format nil "^@~%")))))
     ;; exits if received "bye"
     (cond ((equal "bye" (string-right-trim '(#\Return #\Newline) data-str))
        (as:close-socket socket)
        (format t "Client disconnected.~%"))
           (t (format t "~a" data-str) ; echo on the server side
          (as:write-socket-data socket "Send to server > ")))))
     ;; handle SIGINT
     :event-cb (as:signal-handler 2 (lambda (sig)
                      (declare (ignore sig))
                      (as:free-signal-handler 2)
                      (as:exit-event-loop)))
     :connect-cb (lambda (socket)
           (format t "Client connected.~%")
           (as:write-socket-data socket "Send to server > "))))

(as:start-event-loop #'my-tcp-server)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [Event callbacks (and error handling in general)](https://orthecreedence.github.io/cl-async/event-handling)?

Comment: So I guess my question should be how `as:signal-handler` fits in `handler-case` then.

Comment: From the docs and examples it looks to me like you have the `AS:SIGNAL-HANDLER` in the wrong place. The doc says that it returns `NIL`, not a callback function. The `EVENT-CB` should be a function that takes a single argument, the event. Looking at the docs, it seems like `EVENT-CB` is a regular parameter too, not a keyword.

Comment: Yes, `EVENT-CB` is not the keyword in the document, but it is deprecated now and document is not updated.  Here is the warning you get: `WARNING:
   Passing event-cb as the fourth argument to tcp-server is now deprecated. Please use the :event-cb keyword instead.`

Comment: > @jkiiski, Thank you for pointing out the position of `AS:SIGNAL-HANDLER`.  So I didn't have to combine the `SIGNAL-HANDLER` and the error handlers together!